# Unable to broadcast multi-sig transaction that has been double signed

Tags: bitcoind, electrum, broadcast

Having same issue as [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50176/16-mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed-non-canonical-der-signature-code-26) trying on both electrum wallet in terminal and via coinb.in/#broadcast. Unclear from existing answer how to resolve

#### In terminal

Electrum v 2.7.9; Debian system

```
$ electrum broadcast <tx id>
> Daemon not running; try 'electrum daemon start'
$ electrum daemon start
> starting daemon (PID 12639)
$ electrum broadcast <tx id>
> Daemon not running; try 'electrum daemon start'
```

#### Via coinb.in

On coinb.in/#sign --> "The above transaction has been signed"
So, to broadcast:

> 16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Operation not valid with the current stack size)

I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it. Any help appreciated.

**edit**, transaction: `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`

Comment: Could you post the raw transaction here?

Comment: @MeshCollider OP has been updated to include the transaction hex

Answer (score 1):

The first input of your transaction spends a P2SH 2-of-3 multisig output, but only contains 1 signature. It needs 2.

Comment: Thanks--will have to check with counterparty who said they had signed it.